# no matches for kind "VerticalPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2"

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy a VerticalPodAutoscaler but i get this error:

> error: unable to recognize "scaleCPUVertical.yaml": no matches for
>   kind "VerticalPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2"

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: test1
  namespace: default
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       test1
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Off"
```

Comment: did you check troubleshooting section here https://github.com/openshift/kubernetes-autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#troubleshooting?

Comment: ok i need to install recommender, updater and admission-controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/) as your cloud platform you can follow the guide [Configuring vertical pod autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/vertical-pod-autoscaling), which describes how to create a Kubernetes cluster with [Vertical Pod Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler) enabled.

You should set the desired zone and region, once this is done you can use following command:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] --enable-vertical-pod-autoscaling
```

This will create a new Kubernetes cluster with Vertical Pod Autoscaling enabled and ready to use.

You can also enable it on already running cluster by using the following command:

```
gcloud beta container clusters update [CLUSTER-NAME] --enable-vertical-pod-autoscaling
```

If you are using **AWS** as your cloud provide or Kubernetes on-premise you can follow [Deploy the Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/vertical-pod-autoscaler.html). Which describes how to clone the [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) repository and how to deploy it.